# How can I show usermeta check box value if checked

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox

I’m using this code in a form template that collects usermeta information on my wordpress install.

```
$fields = array();
$fields[] = new PMProRH_Field("agree", "checkbox", array("profile"=>true, "label"=>"Agree",     "options"=>array(""=>"Agree")));
foreach($fields as $field)
pmprorh_add_registration_field("after_email", $field);
```

and then I’m using this to display the usermeta data in a custom author template outside of the loop.

```
    <?php echo $curauth->agree; ?>
```

The problem is that in my author template, all my entry shows is a “1” if checked and a “0” if unchecked. My text fields, radio fields, and select fields all seem to capture the entry value I'm looking for. I need it to echo the value for the checkbox, not the fact that it is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the value is either 1 or 0 but you can of course swop it for whatever you want

e.g.

```
if($curauth->agree):
   $curauth->agree='agree';
else:
   $curauth->agree='dont agree';
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks so much David! That was the ticket! I needed to edit the statement a little to work with my template. I also removed the text with the else condition so that the space is invisible if there is no value (unchecked).

    <?php if($curauth->agree): 
    echo $curauth->agree='agree';
        else:
       echo $curauth->agree='';
    endif; ?>